# Programatically export MySql Database into CSV using PHP/Joomla

Tags: php, database, csv, joomla, export

Using PHP/Joomla, i am trying to export the database backup into CSV/sql file to download. Some tables has huge number of records. When i start the export it gives following error :
**Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded**

Note : I don't want to use the 'max_execution_time' or 'set_time_limit()' or any php.ini settings. Because i will use this script on different client servers & i will not tell to each client to change the settings. 
I need the PHP/Joomla script, not any extensions.

Please help me.

Comment: Have you tried exporting each table to it's own separate file?

Comment: Yes. i tried. some are exporting but at some tables it give execution error.

Comment: You're SOL. If any of those tables requires more than 30 seconds to process, a timeout will occur; even breaking the DB down table by table. And I highly doubt you're going to export them row by row and then use read/write over and over at the server level; that would be such a resource hog.

Comment: Yes. i am doing row by row & then trying to write into table. Is any other way or logic ?

Answer (score 2):

Given your comments to my previous answer I would suggest you look at creating a Joomla! CLI (have a look in the `/cli` directory of your Joomla 2.5+ installation).

We've done a similar thing to what you're for the Pro version of our Easystaging extension which we developed for internal use, to manage client websites with particular content approval processes. The internal version had to deal with our larger clients requirements.

Effectively we created class that inherits from `JApplicationCli` and can be initiated by CRON or from our components user interface.
e.g.

```
class EasyStaging_PlanRunner extends JApplicationCli
{
    /**
     * Entry point for the plan funner (yes it's more fun)
     *
     * @return  void
     *
     * @since   2.5
     */
    public function doExecute()
    {
    }
}
```

If it's launched by the user from within Joomla we use a utility method to make sure the system forks it off correctly:

```
/**
 * Runs the script in the background by scheduling it with the `at` daemon and returns the result
 *
 * @param   string  $pathToScript  A path to the script to run e.g. "/path/to/my/cli/app.php"
 *
 * @return  int
 */
private function _runScriptInBackground($pathToScript)
{
    $cmdPath = "/usr/bin/php -q $pathToScript";

    // We need '2>&1' so we have something to pass back
    $cmd     = 'echo "' . $cmdPath . '" | at now 2>&1';
    $result = shell_exec($cmd);

    return $result;
}
```

Since this is running effectively as a command line script a lot of the limits are much looser but they still won't get you around a very large table. (Some of our clients have many thousands of article or worse K2 content items).

To get around this we wrote an export method called from our `doExecute()`'s main dispatch loop to retrieve and export table rows in reasonable batches. For us *reasonable* was determined by the remote databases `max_allowed_packet` value and we create an SQL file with statements that fit in this limit with a small allowance for various overheads. You may not have these issues but even so you should probably break up your SQL into reasonable sized `insert` statements.

Once the plan has finished running we then zip up all the files and send them off to archive.

Answer (score 1):

Since some tables have huge amount of data, it will take quite some time. As a result the connection would timeout and the export will fail.

A better approach would be to use the command line to dump the data as SQL. You might want to look at the mysqldump command.

You can also invoke the mysqldump command from a PHP script like this -

```
<?php
# Database Settings
$tmpDir = "/home/<username>/tmp/"; // Temp location the user has access to
$user = "<username>_******"; // MySQL Username for the database
$password = "*******"; // MySQL Password
$dbName = "<username>_******"; // Database name, usually in the pattern: <username>_<dbname>
$dbHost = "localhost"; // Mysql server hostname, usually localhost

$sqlFile = $tmpDir . $dbName . date('Y_m_d') . ".sql"; // The dumped SQL File
$attachment = $tmpDir . $dbName . "_" . date('Y_m_d') . ".tgz"; // TGZed file

$creatBackup = "mysqldump -h '" . $dbHost .  "' -u '" . $user . "' --password='" . $password . "' '" . $dbName . "' > '" . $sqlFile . "'"; // Full command
$createZip = "tar cvzf $attachment $sqlFile"; // Full Command

// Execute 'em
system($creatBackup);
system($createZip);
```

This should create a SQL dump and create an archive out of it.

The above codes are part of a tool I built to email me daily backups of my databases. You can check it out on Github and modify it to suit your purposes - https://github.com/masnun/mysql-backup-to-email

Comment: I tried it. but now working. Is any library needed to include ? I only changed the DB connection settings.

Comment: Please make sure that the mysqldump command is available. On a Linux server, this is usually part of mysql-client package. If you are on a shared server, you most likely have it already. 

No external libraries are necessary.

Comment: I am creating a extension & this will use on different servers. So this will not work if mysqldump command is not installed. Is any other way or logic ?

Comment: @Joomladev The only way you can dump a large database is through command line without any limitation on execution period. You can also write your own php script to be run on the command line for an indefinite period of time while dumping data. 

mysqldump is the easiest solution in that context. and it's available on most servers. and easily installable on VPS/dedicated machines. in fact it comes with the mysql command line client on most Linux distros.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you even have to split the records of each table into different files.

Comment: I think, this will not work. because i have huge data in many tables & i will run this script every day.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that instead of re-inventing the wheel you use [Akeeba Backup](https://www.akeebabackup.com/products/akeeba-backup.html) as it will allow you to create automated backups of your entire site, or just the files or specific directories, or just the database or specific tables or any combination you can think of.

It's also free.

[It's won awards year after year, highly](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-security/backup/1606) rated on the [Joomla Extension Directory](http://extensions.joomla.org/) and we use it on all of our sites and our client sites.

If you get [the Pro version](https://www.akeebabackup.com/products/46-software/405-akeeba-core-vs-professional.html), you can even backup to Amazon's S3 or other useful systems.

I have no affiliation with Akeeba other than I love using their products — they let me sleep at night.

Comment: This is MUCH easier that spending a bunch of time trying to get it to work yourself. Especially since you are planning on using this on different client servers. Akeeba makes it trivial to move a site from one server to another. Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Yes i know akeeba is very good but I am creating a extension/product. So i can't tell to each client that use Akeeba to backup the data. If i create my script then i will use it as a cronjob as well.

Comment: Ok, it wasn't clear from your question that you were trying to do this as part of a component — have a look at my new answer for something similar we've done. Cheers :D